# where to put cypress tests: with front end code or own repo?

Tags: continuous-integration, integration-testing, cypress

I am new to Cypress and trying to find the best practices for where to store our tests.  I see there seems to be plenty of resources for how to organize folders to setup fixtures, tests, plugins, etc. but I can't seem to find any recommendations if people actually store the tests with the front-end code that's being tested or in it's own separate repo?

Are there any advantages of one or the other when trying to setup CICD?

Comment: Could I first ask the question about what type of test these are?

Cypress tests can be quite heavy in terms of a full setup of folder structure etc, are these unit level tests or integration/ui/e2e tests?

Comment: We are using these as integration tests so I guess they require both a front end and backing api (different repos) to be stood up

Comment: Then i would recommend having your test framework setup in a seperate repo. In our scenario we use Docker and our front end and back end are stood up using a docker-compose file and the tests run against those components.

Answer (score 7):

It is highly recommended to store tests within the same code base or repository as your application or front-end code for the following reasons:

- Often new code changes need to be coupled with accompanying tests or pre-existing tests need to be updated to validate the new behavior or functionality.
- It is important to see new code alongside related tests during the code review process.
- Tests that run within the CI process after every commit or pull-request (PR) against your front-end can defend against merging in faulty or error-prone code. It is much easier to integrate CI within a PR workflow.

Tests living within the application repository is the most common pattern, but your ability have this implementation may vary based on your project, team/organization structure, or tech debt limitations.